# Import packages from current project directory in VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I build or debug a particular file in my Python project (which imports a user defined package) I get an import error. How can I solve this problem?

test.py

```
def sum(a,b):
    return a+b
```

test2.py

```
from test import sum
sum(3,4)
```

The above code will give an import error `cannot import test`.

Directory tree

```
├── graphs
│   ├── Dijkstra's\ Algorithm.py
│   ├── Floyd\ Warshall\ DP.py
│   ├── Kruskal's\ algorithm.py
│   ├── Prim's\ Algoritm.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── graph.py
├── heap
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── heap.py
│   └── priority_queue.py
```

Trying to import in graphs;

```
from heap.heap import Heap
```

Comment: could you show your directory tree ?

Comment: @shutdown-hnow added directory structure

Answer (score 0):

About the `heap` file, make sure that you are running on the project root folder.

If these `test.py` files are running on the same folder, try to add a `__init__.py` empty file on this folder.

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later (deeper) on the module search path. In the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialisation code for the package or set the `__all__` variable, described later.